# Error: Invalid number format while sending SMS with SIM800L

Tags: sms, gsm, at-command, sim900

I'm using a SIM800L GSM module connected over USB-Serial to my computer.
When I try to send a SMS I got an error:

```
AT+CMGS="+4915xxxxxxxxx"
> Test (Ctrl+Z)
+CMS ERROR: Invalid number format (incomplete number)
```

I’m obviously connected to the network because pin is entered +CREG an +COPS seems good.

```
AT+CPIN?
+CPIN: READY

OK
AT+CREG?
+CREG: 0,1

OK
AT+COPS?
+COPS: 0,0,"O2 (Germany)"

OK
```

As well I can receive SMS and see incoming calls.
I set the module in sms text mode and use the coding GSM

```
AT+CMGF?
+CMGF: 1

OK
AT+CSCS?
+CSCS: "GSM"

OK
```

I try different number formats like "015xxxxxxxxx" or "004915xxxxxxxxx". Also I try different values for the optional  parameter from +CMGS

Could anybody advise me what to do?

Comment: Its strange. can you share your code for sending sms?

Comment: Mostly I send commands over a Serial-USB adapter from my PC. I also try  an Arduino Uno with this [code](http://pastebin.com/eMG99q2x)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To send SMS it was necessary for me to change the SMSC adress with the command AT+CSCA.

```
AT+CSCA="+491760000443",145
```

The SMSC you can found at your mobile operator. In my case Netzclub at O2 Germany.